# tableView with imageView with storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, imageview, tableview

I have a table view in my app and I am trying to add a image view over the top of it (see image below). However whenever I do this the image view is just instantly added to a cell in the table view. Am I not allowed to add an image view to a table view like this?

[image]

Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated. Thank you!
Sean

Comment: saen g use `uiviewcontrller`

Comment: I guess you want to make you cells static and in the last cell you want an image right?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that, not if you're using a UITableViewController. If you want other UI elements in your view that are not subviews of the table view, you need to use a UIViewController instead. Just remember to make that view controller the data source and delegate of your table view, and make an outlet to the table view if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a UIViewController as your parent view, then create a Container View with an embed segue to your table view controller. Check out my answer [here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730440/how-to-setup-a-static-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uiview/19731280#19731280).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, sure -- you can do that.  Add a UIImageView as a subview to the UITableView.  For example:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPositionInTableView, yPositionInTableView, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
image.image = theUIImage;
[tableView addSubview:image];
```

Comment: Not seeing any mention of a UITableViewController in your question like rdelmar cited in his answer, so this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Simply drag a UIImageView and add it under the UITableView in your XIB or storyboard, like the picture below:

[image]

But if you add image view directly to your table view, the image would appear after or before all cells, according to the position of your image view in your designer.

For the interface you are trying, I will not recommend you to add the image view directly under your table view. Simply put it on the parent view of that UITableView and above that UITableView and anchor it accordingly to the bottom of the parent view and you are all set.